# How to connect to Oracle DB in Haskell

Tags: oracle, haskell, odbc, hdbc

Can anyone share some tips on how to connect to Oracle DB using Haskell? I found it quite difficult. What I've done so far:

(1) Checked out Persistent's documentation, on this page http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent it mentions all the mainstream one but Oracle.

(2) Got this book "Developing Web Apps with Haskell and Yesod", no mention of Oracle

(3) Following http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html I checked out HDBC odbc, found this page https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-odbc the instruction in the bottom is hard to follow because some of the required binaries can't be found on homebrew on Mac.

Just curious, how other engineers are connecting to Oracle using Haskell?

I've asked this question on #haskell-beginners #haskell-web IRC channels, no feedback so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `persistent` does support Oracle. https://github.com/gbwey/persistent-odbc

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the issue is persistent-odbc library still depends on HDBC-odbc, we still gonna ran into problem (3) in the question.

Comment: @ShawnLu Did you end up figuring this out? I am having difficulties trying to do the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932715/how-do-i-connect-haskell-hdbc-to-an-oracle-db-on-mac