# How do I connect Haskell HDBC to an oracle db on osx

Tags: oracle, macos, haskell, odbc, hdbc

I was wondering how you are supposed to connect to an oracle db on mac with Haskell HDBC.

I tried doing it through ODBC, by running `brew install unixobcd` and then installing oracle instant client basic and obdc into a directory. Then in Haskell, with HDBC and HDBC-odbc both installed, calling `connectODBC` with `Driver` set to the location of `libsqora.dylib.12.1` in said directory.

It is giving me `sot-dba: SqlError {seState = "[\"01000\"]", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "connectODBC/sqlDriverConnect: [\"0: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '<valid absolute path to libsqora.dylib.12.1>' : file not found\"]"}`, but when I `cat` that location it spills out the appropriate unreadably binary, so its definitely a valid file location.

I was wondering if anyone could either help debug my issue, or just give me instructions on how to set it up from scratch and I will happily do it over properly. I just have no idea where to go from here since it is claiming a file doesn't exist that does, and I am having trouble finding many results on google on how to debug that.

One thing perhaps worth noting is that I ran `./odbc_update_ini.sh /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4` to set up the oracle odbc driver, because that is the location that brew put unixodbc, was that perhaps incorrect?

If necessary I could consider a different library than HDBC, but I would strongly prefer not having to, it seems like some other libraries such as persistent actually use hdbc/hdbc-odbc under the covers anyway, so surely this shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Does a tool like `isql` work for you with this driver?

Comment: @Arnon How do I connect `isql` to an oracle db? When I google it I just get a huge amount of isql\*plus and sql\*plus noise instead of an answer.

Comment: Well, you want to test that unixOdbc actually functions and your DSN/driver is correct. Single out unixOdbc before attempting the Haskell bit....
This man-page has some samples
https://www.mankier.com/1/isql

Comment: I looked at the man page but I don't see how to pass in the connection string, so things like the driver, the server protocol / host / port and the service name.

Comment: You define the parameters like user/port/etc... in the DSN settings...
https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/create-an-odbc-dsn-on-linux

Comment: @Arnon Ok `isql <name>` works fine now, but `connectODBC "DSN=<name>"` is still giving me `[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib <valid path to libsqora.dylib.12.1>' : file not found`.

Comment: Do you have Instant Client in ~/lib ? See the Instant Client installation instructions for details: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html#ic_osx_inst

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!